# Project Euler # 51 c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve problem 51 in project euler.

Here is the problem statement : [Project Euler Problem 51](https://projecteuler.net/problem=51)

I tried the approach given below.

1. Generate all the prime numbers between 2 and 10 power 8 using Sieve of Eratosthenes
2. Gather all n-digit numbers from sieve (i.e .. first i will get all 3 digits, then 4 digits .. so on and compute on it)
3. check if the number has repeated digit (as per problem statement we have 2 *s of same digit) . If yes , convert into string
4. if yes, find the position where it repeats and save it as a key (for ex: 12341 will result 04 as key since 1 is the number which is repeated in 0 and 4th position)
5. now based on the key , insert into the bucket (Bucket is a multimap which contains key as repeated position (04) and value as the prime number)
6. For each key in bucket, delete the repeated position . If am taking 04 bucket key , then all the prime numbers in that bucket would have the strings repeated in the positions 0 and 4. Am deleting 0th and 4th position of the string which would result my number (12341) as 234 and insert it into a map , which will store the occurence as (234, 8 being the trimmed number and number of occurences).
7. Now, if the key 234 is repeated 8 times, find the numbers which got trimmed and resulted 234. Those are the answers.

I ran this algorithm in c++ , and for 7 primes 56003, 56113, 56333, 56443, 56663, 56773, and 56993 is resulting less than a second ..

but , for 8 digits , i crossed 10 power 8 primes and still it didnt result any answer. I believe answer is above that limit.

And when i try to generate primes between 2 and 10 power 9 its aborting , since i am storing all the numbers in vector.

My question is ,

Is there any way by which we can fine tune the above mentioned steps and find the answer, 
or i need to think some other way to find the answer .

Note: Just for an example i took 12341.

Comment: How does this get upvotes!?

Comment: Mohit Jain, i wanted to know if this approach is atleast fit enough to find the solution. If yes is the answer , i will post the code. Code is too big :-)

Comment: The problem statement does not require a digit to be repeated - the first example is even an example of a one-digit replacement - and neither does it require only one repetition. (The answer could be *1**1*1, for instance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is atleast one issue in your brute force solution. You are assuming exactly 2 digits are `*` but question never mentions this. There may be 1 or 3 or more digits which when replaced with the **same** digits `0-9` still generate primes.

It is impossible to have 8 prime with 1 or 2 `*` for the following reason:

- If you use just 1 `*`, and let's say replace it with 1 to get a prime(let's call this prime p). Now if `p % 3 = 1`, you can not replace `*` with `0`, `3` and `6` otherwise the number would become composite(divisible by 3). Throwing away 3 candidates makes it impossible to generate another prime. Next case if `p % 3 = 2` you can not replace `*` with `2`, `5` and `8` for the same reason. Making 8-primes with one `*` impossible for any number of digits.
- If you use just 2 `*`, and let's say replace both with 1 to get a prime(let's call this prime p). Now if `p % 3 = 2`, you can not replace both `*` with `0`, `3` and `6` otherwise the number would become composite(divisible by 3). Throwing away 3 candidates makes it impossible to generate another prime. Next case if `p % 3 = 1` you can not replace `*` with `2`, `5` and `8` for the same reason. Making 8-primes with two `*` impossible for any number of digits.

This is the reason why your code does not give the required output. You should perhaps try with 3 `*` characters.

Comment: yes Mohit Jain.. I assumed only 2 *s.. Thanks for the clarification. I will restructure the algorithm. But , if the answer crosses 10 power 9 , then what would be the replacement for sieve of Eratosthenes (For now i will believe that answer would be below 10 power 8 :P). Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: OK, in that case you would need a cleverer algorithm and not just brute force algorithm. If you need a hint, the number is less than 8 digits.